# How to create fake Virtus model returned objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using [virtus gem](https://github.com/solnic/virtus) and I have a doubt:

I have a method that returns a virtus object. But I want to unit test the calling class.

In order to do this, i want to fake its return.

Usually I use Factory girl to create fake objects, but it din't work for virtus.

How you recommend that I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to switch to [fabrication](http://www.fabricationgem.org/) which implements factory pattern for absolutely anything that can be initiated ;))

If it's not an option, you can define your test/spec helper that will create an object for you. In this case you would probably like to use [faker](https://github.com/stympy/faker):

```
def create_my_model(opts = {})
  MyModel.new({
    :foo => opts.fetch(:foo) { "Dynamic Default Foo #{rand}" },
    :bar => opts.fetch(:bar, "Static Default Baz")
  })
end
```